# Sub menus have disappeared

Tags: php, wordpress, drop-down-menu

My web site has suddenly come down with some problems, with no known changes.  Most prominently, no sub menus appear.  The html is there, everything appears to be there in wordpress in the admin panel to be set up right.  But no sub menus appear on hover.  Site is btwimages.com.

```
  <!--  ################ TOP MENU SECTION ################ -->
    <!-- **Top-Menu** -->
    <div id="top-menu">
        <div class="container">
        <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-2351" class="home menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home"><span class="hoverL"> <span class="hoverR"> </span> </span><a href="http://www.btwimages.com">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-2352" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children"><span class="hoverL"> <span class="hoverR"> </span> </span><a href="#">About Us</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-2316" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.btwimages.com/about-us/about-btw-images/">About BTW images</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2318" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.btwimages.com/about-us/testimonials/">Testimonials</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2317" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.btwimages.com/about-us/our-team/">Our Team</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-2353" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children"><span class="hoverL"> <span class="hoverR"> </span> </span><a href="#">Services</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-2354" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children"><a href="#">Real Estate</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-2341" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.btwimages.com/services-2/real-estate/photography/">Photography</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-2340" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.btwimages.com/services-2/real-estate/floor-plans/">Floor Plans</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-2343" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.btwimages.com/services-2/real-estate/virtual-tours/">Virtual Tours</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-2342" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.btwimages.com/services-2/real-estate/video-tours/">Video Tours</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-2339" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.btwimages.com/services-2/real-estate/brochures/">Brochures</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-3454" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.btwimages.com/services-2/real-estate/truevision/">TrueVision</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="menu-item-2888" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.btwimages.com/services-2/3d-immersion/">3D Immersion</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-3098" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.btwimages.com/services-2/virtual-staging/">Virtual Staging</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2344" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.btwimages.com/services-2/video/">Video</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2336" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.btwimages.com/services-2/general-photography/">General Photography</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2337" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.btwimages.com/services-2/marketing/">Marketing</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-2329" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><span class="hoverL"> <span class="hoverR"> </span> </span><a href="http://www.btwimages.com/portfolio/">Portfolio</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-2355" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children"><span class="hoverL"> <span class="hoverR"> </span> </span><a href="#">Pricing</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-2333" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.btwimages.com/pricing/real-estate-photography/">Real Estate Photography</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2912" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.btwimages.com/pricing/3d-immersion-tour/">3D Immersion Tour</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2331" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.btwimages.com/pricing/floor-plans/">Floor Plans</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2332" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.btwimages.com/pricing/printing/">Brochures</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-3099" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.btwimages.com/services-2/virtual-staging/">Virtual Staging</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-3455" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.btwimages.com/services-2/real-estate/truevision/">TrueVision</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-2356" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children"><span class="hoverL"> <span class="hoverR"> </span> </span><a href="#">News</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-2328" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.btwimages.com/news/latest-news/">Latest News</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2325" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.btwimages.com/news/btween-the-lines/">BTWeen the lines</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2327" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.btwimages.com/news/latest-home-tours/">Latest Home Tours</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-2357" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children"><span class="hoverL"> <span class="hoverR"> </span> </span><a href="#">Support</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-2482" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.btwimages.com/support/faq/">FAQ</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2910" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.btwimages.com/support/3d-immersion-faqs/">3D Immersion FAQs</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2347" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.btwimages.com/support/help-videos/">Help Videos</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2349" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.btwimages.com/support/preparation-checklist/">Preparation Checklist</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2348" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.btwimages.com/support/media-terms-of-use/">Media Terms of Use</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2350" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.btwimages.com/support/service-policies/">Service Policies</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-2358" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children"><span class="hoverL"> <span class="hoverR"> </span> </span><a href="#">Contact  Us</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-2320" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.btwimages.com/contact-us/learn-more/">Learn More</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2321" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.btwimages.com/contact-us/request-service/">Request Service</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>        </div>
    </div><!-- **Top-Menu - End** -->
    <!--  ################ TOP MENU SECTION END ################ -->
```

Comment: Have you installed any new plugins?

Comment: Just posting some HTML won't really help us help you. We have no idea how your submenu should work, if it uses css-hover, js or if the above html is correct or not. Is it a plugin? Custom code? Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Also, what do you mean when you say _"everything appears to be there in wordpress in the admin panel"_. "Everything" like what?

Comment: The actual menu structure using the wordpress GUI with children and the location selected is there.  The HTML in the page source is there.  Nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't fixed it through admin panel, you can add this code to your header or footer:

```
jQuery('.menu-item-has-children').hover(function() {
    jQuery('.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu').css('display', 'none');
    jQuery(this).find('.sub-menu').css('display', 'block');
});
```

Comment: Still didn't seem to help.  Even the admin bar across the top of the site that should be there when I'm logged into wordpress and viewing the site (the black bar with edit page on it) does not appear.

Comment: It appears my footer.php is not loading, any ideas?

Comment: @TJWJR seems there's an error somewhere in the codes that stops some of the scripts from running. try enabling debug mode to see the problem

Comment: @TJWJR i checked your website and submenu is working already huh?